# redissonClient.poll() only returning the first 8 characters of String type value

Tags: spring-boot, redis, redisson

Currently using reddison, creating a redissonClient and trying to poll data from redis server. I can see the data in the redis db if I check via redis-cli but when I look at the string value in my java application it is always the first 8 characters of the string and no more. Not sure why it won't give me the whole value.

I've tried using the .peek() method as well and I see the same symptom in that I only get 8 characters of the string returned.

Here is the main part of the code I can provide more details as needed:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class RedisConsumer {

RedisConfig redisConfig;
//RQueue<String> redisQueue;
RBlockingQueue<String> redisQueue;

@Autowired
RedisConsumer(RedisConfig redisConfig) {
    this.redisConfig = redisConfig;
}

public void pollAuditQueue() {

    //Redisson
    redisQueue.add("{JSON string here snipped out for brevity}");
    String item = redisQueue.poll();

    if (!Objects.isNull(item)) {
        log.info("I found this item: " + item);

    } else {
       log.info("Nothing in queue...");
   }
}

@PostConstruct
private void init() throws Exception {
    RedissonClient redissonClient = redisConfig.redisson();
    redisQueue = redissonClient.getBlockingQueue("test");

    while(true) {
        pollAuditQueue();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

When I look at the print statement in my console I see:

```
I found this item: {"AuditEv
```

When I check the redis-cli I can see the whole value:

```
1) "\xfc\t{\"AuditEvent\":{\"timestamp\":\"2018-11-27 04:31:47.818000+0000\" snipped the rest out for brevity}"
```

Lastly if I check that the item was removed from Redis after being polled in the Java app I can confirm that it is.

Any help would be great since it's not throwing any specific error I'm not finding any resources online to help address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found one thing I didn't notice in my earlier testing. When I manually insert using the redis cli I was replicating what my first tests through Java did which put the \xfc\t at the front which can be seen in my sample above.

Just now when I used redisQueue.add from within my application I noticed in redis it has \xfc\x80\x90\x01 instead and those do return the entire string to me in my application. I assume then this has to do with memory allocation somehow? I'm marking the question as resolved as I am no longer experiencing the issue. If anyone can drop on comment on what those letter/numbers mean though it may be meaningful for anyone that reads this post later. Once I have researched it I will add that comment myself if no one has beat me to it!

Comment: These letters are object header written by FstCodec

Answer (score 0):

Add encoding:

```
RMap map = redisson.getMap("SessionMap"); -->
RMap map = redisson.getMap("SessionMap", new StringCodec("UTF-8"));
```